# Output from HTTPConnection debug level when using python's http.client

Tags: python-3.x, urllib2

I'm trying to get debug information from python's built in httpclient. In a console I tried

```py
from http.client import HTTPSConnection
HTTPSConnection.debuglevel = 1

a_url = 'https://feeds.simplecast.com/wgl4xEgL'
from urllib.request import urlopen
response = urlopen(a_url)
```

I expected to see some debug output either to `stdout` or `stderr` but don't see any output. I tried using the `HTTPSConnection.set_debuglevel` method too. How can I see the debug output?

EDIT : Realized I was using `HTTPConnection` I tried `HTTPSConnection` and updated that snippet above to reflect that.